# In docker, how can I pass through all found nvidia devices to a container?

Tags: docker, coreos

I'm netbooting CoreOS with Nvidia and want to pass through to a container all found nvidia devices.

How do I do this from the command line when some machines have more GPU cards than others.

i.e. I'd like to do something like:

```
docker run --name cuda_app --devices=/dev/nvidia*:/dev/nvidia* cuda_app
```

On some machines, there could be /dev/nvidia0 - 2, on others nvidia0 - 8 for example.

Comment: I'm not sure docker command syntax supports something like this directly. But you still have a few options, e.g. you can wrap the command in a bash script or you can pass an entire /dev/ directory (although this is not nice), you can even run --privileged (but this is bad unless you really want to do it).

Comment: I think you're right, I may have to wrap it.  Pity --devices=major,minor syntax isn't supported with wildcard like the old lxc method of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the list of device to expose using an inlined bash script

```
docker run --name cuda_app $(for dev in /dev/nvidia*; do echo -n "--device $dev:$dev "; done) cuda_app
```